# How to use scoped_model with Shared Preferences?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am add state management to my chat app using scoped_model.

My question is how use scoped_model with shared preferences. So on app startup Model state is fill with values from shared preferences. For example stored `username` will be retrieve from shared preferences and then store in `UserModel` `username` state.

I have look but no find tutorial how to do.

I have find this sample from FlutterCinematic [main.dart](https://github.com/aaronoe/FlutterCinematic/blob/master/lib/main.dart):

```
void main() async { 
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    runApp(ScopedModel<AppModel>(
    model: AppModel(sharedPreferences), child: CinematicApp()));
    }
```

Is this best way to do? 
What is best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while since this question was asked. But I am still gonna' answer it anyway.

I had the same problem when I was developing an android app using shared preferences and scoped model. My idea was to initialize the values in scopedmodel when the app starts. And the way I did it was to call the function within the constructor of the model.

Let's say my scoped model is:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
   String variable1;
   String variable2;
   int variable3;

   //Getter functions go here

   //Setter function (though not a pure setter but a function that sets the values)
   void setValues() {
        SharedPreferences.getInstance().then(
            (prefs) {
                        variable1 = prefs.getString('var1');
                        variable2 = prefs.getString('var2');
                        variable3 = prefs.getInt('var3');
          ));
       }

     AppModel(
           setValues();
      );
}
```

Now when you initialize the model before the Material app, its values will get initialized.